# Reduce callback nesting in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-origin

I've read that in Cypress I should not use `await` and that it is not needed because you can remove nesting through chaining. Here I have a `cy.fixure` nested in `cy.origin` nested in `cy.session`, is there a way to flatten this?

```js
  cy.session([], () => {
    cy.visit("")
    cy.origin("https://my-address.com", () => {
      cy.fixture("user").then((user) => {
        cy.get("#username").type(user.username)
        cy.get("#password").type(user.password)
      })

      cy.get("button[type='submit']").click()
      cy.url().should("equal", "/login-success")
    })
  })
```

**Edit**
This is not a question regarding regular javascript, it's [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) specific and normal async / await won't work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Comment: [You should be using async await in modern JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250697/542251)

Comment: Cypress does not use real promises, it uses a promise-like syntax so regular JS answers won't like ansyc / await won't cut it.

Comment: @Liam es6-promise tag is misleading.

Comment: [Well use this option then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250693/542251)

Comment: Just because there is a `.then()` method, does not mean it's a promise. You can add a `.then` property to any object, but you can't `await` it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really (any way to flatten). As you said, async/await does not work with Cypress commands since they aren't promises.

Well, you can put promises in place and await them, but it's clumsy and actually more code.

But `cy.session()` and `cy.origin()` are funky commands that only work because of the callback - or more accurately require the callback to function.

`cy.session()` only fires it's callback on the first call, there-after it caches the session data and returns them on the 2nd call instead of re-calling the callback.

`cy.origin()` uses the callback to make an isolated sandbox for code running against the other (specified) origin, and it's not even a callback in the Javascript sense, since it cannot use closure to variables in the outside scope.

Which links in to the `fixture()` part. Normally you can import or require a fixture

```js
const user = require('cypress/fixtures/user.json')
```

but with cy.origin that doesn't help you since the fixture in imported in the outer scope and cannot be seen inside the cy.origin sandbox.

---

For a promise-creating plugin see [cypress-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise), but it won't work with session and origin for reasons stated.

```js
import promisify from 'cypress-promise'
 
it('should run tests with async/await', async () => {
  const foo = await promisify(cy.wrap('foo'))
  const bar = await promisify(cy.wrap('bar'))
 
  expect(foo).to.equal('foo')
  expect(bar).to.equal('bar')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough I guess I can mark this as best answer since the answer is "you cannot flatten it"